# Unexpected SerializationException when using IRequiresRequestStream

Tags: deserialization, servicestack

We have a request Dto which is defined as this:

```
public class AddDocumentByUploadBinaryRequest: AddDocumentRequest, IRequiresRequestStream
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public Stream RequestStream { get; set; }
}
```

And AddDocumentRequest class definition is:

```
public class AddDocumentRequest: IReturn<ResponseBase>
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string[] Tags { get; set; }

    public Guid? LotId { get; set; }

    public Guid? ContactId { get; set; }

    // never need it to attach document to existing bill
    //public Guid? BillId { get; set; }

    public Guid? FolioId { get; set; }

    public Guid? JobTaskId { get; set; }

    public Guid? TaskId { get; set; }

    public Guid? TenantInvoiceId { get; set; }

    public Guid? InspectionTaskId { get; set; }

    public Guid? InspectionReportAreaId { get; set; }

    public Guid? InMessageId { get; set; }

    public DocumentTypes? DocumentType { get; set; }

    public EventLinkTypes? DocumentArea {   get; set; }

    public Guid? MessageId { get; set; }

    public Guid? LinkId { 
        get {
            switch (DocumentArea) {
                //case EventLinkTypes.Bill:
                //  return BillId;
                case EventLinkTypes.Contact:
                    return ContactId;
                case EventLinkTypes.Inspection:
                    return InspectionTaskId;
                case EventLinkTypes.InspectionReport:
                    return InspectionTaskId;
                case EventLinkTypes.InspectionReportArea:
                    return InspectionReportAreaId;
                case EventLinkTypes.Job:
                    return JobTaskId;
                case EventLinkTypes.Lot:
                    return LotId;
                case EventLinkTypes.Task:
                    return TaskId;
                case EventLinkTypes.Message:
                    return MessageId;
                default:
                    return FolioId;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The API works most of the time but occassionally, we get "Unable to bind to request" error with the details like this:

> Unable to bind to request 'AddDocumentByUploadBinaryRequest'; Error code: SerializationException; Field name: ���iD�����; Message: '*�Z~�l�_$�6j�Ǒ�Xƾ��ԯ㵂���;W;/�����k� 6��;ׯG$�O�`�V�j�*�a�Z�[S幉>�>����[An��O
>   X�n$�<�p�H��GN��[���c�|5�#��

?�' is an Invalid value for '���iD�����'

The captured error message suggests that the binary body was unexpectedly deserialized and failed.

The client device always uses Content-Type: application/octet-stream header. I have read relevant source code of ServiceStack but I couldn't think of why the binary body would still go into deserialization.

Any ideas would be appreaciated.

Comment: Can you please include the Raw HTTP Headers of a Request that fails.

Comment: A StackTrace would also be helpful. Note it may not be the body causing this as ServiceStack still tries to use the QueryString to populate the Request.